# How to show multiple Highcharts graph on one page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, graph, highcharts, coffeescript

Hi I m trying to display multiple Highcharts graph of different types on one page,
However,I am able to get to show only one graph at a time.

Here is my code to show pie chart:

```
$ ->
  # Note: scheme_distribution is like [['Gold': 50],['Equity': 5],['Debt': 45]]
  scheme_distribution = $("#scheme_distribution_chart").data('distribution')
  ###
  # Create the chart when all data is loaded
  # @returns {undefined}
  ###

  $ ->
    chart = new (Highcharts.Chart)({
      chart:
        renderTo: 'scheme_distribution_chart'
        type: 'pie'
      plotOptions:
        pie:
          innerSize: '60%'
          dataLabels:
            enabled: false
          tooltip:
            headerFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span><small> {point.key}</small>: ',
            pointFormat:'<b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
      series: [ { data: scheme_distribution } ]
      title:
        text: 'Portfolio'
    }, (chart) ->
      # on complete
      textX = chart.plotLeft + chart.series[0].center[0]
      textY = chart.plotTop + chart.series[0].center[1]
      span = '<span id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:relative; text-align:center;">'
      span += '<span style="font-size: 14px">' + scheme_distribution[0][0] + ' ' + scheme_distribution[0][1] + '%</span><br>'
      span += '<span style="font-size: 14px">' + scheme_distribution[1][0] + ' ' + scheme_distribution[1][1] + '%</span><br>'
      span += '<span style="font-size: 14px">' + scheme_distribution[2][0] + ' ' + scheme_distribution[2][1] + '%</span><br>'
      span += '</span>'
      $('#addText').append span
      span = $('#pieChartInfoText')
      span.css 'left', textX + span.width() * -0.4
      span.css 'top', textY + span.height() * -0.5
      return
    )
  return
```

and here is my code for showing series graph:

```
$ ->
  seriesOptions = []
  seriesCounter = 0
  names = [
    'good'
    'bad'
    'average'
  ]
  current_time = new Date();
  # set data
  scenario = $("#portfolio_chart").data('scenario')
  ###
  # Create the chart when all data is loaded
  # @returns {undefined}
  ###

  createChart = ->
    $('#portfolio_chart').highcharts 'StockChart',
      legend:
        enabled: true
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y:25
      rangeSelector: selected: 5
      yAxis:
        labels: formatter: ->
          (if @value > 0 then ' + ' else '') + @value + '%'
        plotLines: [ {
          value: 0
          width: 2
          color: 'silver'
        } ]
      plotOptions:
        series:
          compare: 'value'
          turboThreshold: 0
      tooltip:
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>'
        valueDecimals: 2
        formatter: ->
          if this.x > current_time
            good = this.points[0]
            average = this.points[2]
            bad = this.points[1]
            date = '<b><span style="color: black"><b>Date:</b> ' + new Date(good.x) + '</span></b><br>'
            good_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + good.color + '">' + good.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + good.y + '</b> <br>'
            average_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + average.color + '">' + average.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + average.y + '</b> <br>'
            bad_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + bad.color + '">' + bad.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + bad.y + '</b> <br>'
            return date + good_tooltip + average_tooltip + bad_tooltip;
          else
            average = this.points[2]
            date = '<span style="color: black"><b>Date:</b> ' + new Date(average.x) + '</span></b><br>'
            average_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + average.color + '">' + average.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + average.y + '</b> <br>'
            return date + average_tooltip;
      series: seriesOptions
    return

  $.each names, (i, name) ->
    seriesOptions[i] =
      name: name
      data: scenario[name]
      type: 'spline'
    # As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
    # we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
    seriesCounter += 1
    if seriesCounter == names.length
      createChart()
```

Secondly the second graph js is also used to show graph on different page for different data series.
But it shows only one graph at a time.
I know the query is quite absolute, but I don't know how to explain this in any other way.

Any help or suggestion on how to solve this problem is appreciated.

Thank You!

**EDIT**
If you need any further description or more code on how I am doing this, I ready to provide it.

Comment: scheme_distribution_chart and portfolio_chart present on the HTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7cvCX/313/

Comment: Hi @Ansar yes they are on the same page.

Comment: hi @zubair, thanks for your reply, I think I missed something in my question description. that chart A that your showed is just one pie chart,
however I want to show multiple pie charts in same page with different data in it, how do I achieve this in same js.
thanks for your help.

Comment: you must create multiple object for more than one chart like this http://jsfiddle.net/7cvCX/314/

Comment: hi @Zubairsadiq thankx for the suggestion, actually I am looping over an object of multiple objects, for example i have obj1 which has 5 objects like [1,2,3,4,5] and each of this object has a different  series data. and I have to show pie graph for each of this objects.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YpfBs/127/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/YpfBs/128/)

```
<div id="container" style="height: 600px;"></div>


   var object=[{
            name: "2011",
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Apple",
                    color: "#FF3333",
                    y: 8
                },
                {
                    name: "Banana",
                    color: "#FFF55C",
                    y: 11
                },
                {
                    name: "Pear",
                    color: "#F1FFB8",
                    y: 3
                }
            ],
            center: [150,100],
            size: 150
        },
        {
            name: "2011",
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Apple",
                    color: "#FF3333",
                    y: 8
                },
                {
                    name: "Banana",
                    color: "#FFF55C",
                    y: 11
                },
                {
                    name: "Pear",
                    color: "#F1FFB8",
                    y: 3
                }
            ],
            center: [450,100],
            size: 150
        },
        {
            name: "2013",
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Apple",
                    color: "#FF3333",
                    y: 8
                },
                {
                    name: "Banana",
                    color: "#FFF55C",
                    y: 11
                },
                {
                    name: "Pear",
                    color: "#F1FFB8",
                    y: 3
                }
            ],
            center: [150,300],
            size: 150
        },
        {
            name: "2014",
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Apple",
                    color: "#FF3333",
                    y: 8
                },
                {
                    name: "Banana",
                    color: "#FFF55C",
                    y: 11
                },
                {
                    name: "Pear",
                    color: "#F1FFB8",
                    y: 3
                }
            ],
            center: [450,300],
            size: 150
        }];


 chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Pie Charts",
        align: 'center'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top'
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.key + ': ' + this.y + ' (' + Math.round(this.percentage) + '%)';
        }
    },

    series:object,

});
```

i think you need this add new object of data in object and change center[x,y] value you will get new chart